# Do all RDEPENDS for python need to be explicitly defined in IMAGE_INSTALL_append in Yocto?

Tags: dependencies, dependency-management, yocto

As a part of the creating a Recipe for the InfluxDB-python client. I added all the packages in the `requirements.txt` into the `RDEPEND_${PN}` for example:

```
RDEPENDS_${PN} = " python3-requests python3-json python3-dateutil python3-six"
```

However is it a necessity to add the above mentioned dependencies in the `local.conf` file as follows?:

```
  IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " python3-six python3-dateutil python3-json"
```

Does `RDEPENDS` not install it *accordingly*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RDEPENDS` means run time dependency. So `do_rootfs` automatically adds all the packages listed as RDEPENDS into the final image.

Only thing you should consider is, your package should be part of the image which you are compiling.

For example, assume `core-image-minimal.bb` is the recipe for your final image, you should somewhere in `.bbappend` or in `.bb` of this image file add your recipe name, i.e for example `my-package.bb`.

When building `bitbake core-image-minimal`, your package `my-package` and also it's runtime dependencies are automatically added.

Comment: does it make sense to append the final image or is it okay to add for example `influxdb-python` in the `local.conf`?

Comment: `local.conf` is created after sourcing of oe. If you want your application used many others, it make sense to add in image recipe. Or if you are just testing and using yourself, you can just add in local.conf

Comment: @Shan-Desai: Accept the answer if it answers your question ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue was newer version of Yocto with new `override` syntax,
so the fix was:

```
-RDEPENDS_${PN} += "python3-json"
+RDEPENDS:${PN} += "python3-json"
```

To detect the problem, I added non-existing package to old `RDEPENDS_${PN}` and I still was able to `bitbake` it, so it gave a clue that it is not in use.